# Python Caesar cipher problem to decrypt with high key

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I wrote a code that executes Caesar Cipher for a text file.

Everything works great if I use the key up to 26.
From key 26, it fails to execute decrypt properly.

what could be the problem?

This is the function of the Caesar Cipher:

```
def CaesarCipher(message, shift):
    """Encrypts or Decrypts the message"""
    message = message.lower()
    secret = ""
    for code in message:
        if code in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            num = ord(code)
            num += shift
            if num > ord("z"): 
                num -= 26
            elif num < ord("a"):
                num += 26
            secret = secret + chr(num)
        else:
            # don't modify any non-letters in the message; just add them as-is
            secret = secret + code
    return secret
```

That's the full code:

```
"""
Caesar Cipher code for
Encrypts or Decrypts txt file
"""


def CaesarCipher(message, shift):
    """Encrypts or Decrypts the message"""
    message = message.lower()
    secret = ""
    for code in message:
        if code in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            num = ord(code)
            num += shift
            if num > ord("z"): 
                num -= 26
            elif num < ord("a"):
                num += 26
            secret = secret + chr(num)
        else:
            # don't modify any non-letters in the message; just add them as-is
            secret = secret + code
    return secret


def encrypt(message, key):
    """Encrypts the message"""
    return CaesarCipher(message, key)


def decrypt(message, key):
    """Decrypts the message"""
    return CaesarCipher(message, -key)


try:
    options = int(input("1.Encode\n2.Decode\n"))
except ValueError:
    print("Use only in integers!")
    exit(-1)
except:
    print("use only in integers!")
    exit(-1)

if options == 1:
    print("You have chosen to encrypt a file")
    fileDest = input("Please enter the path to the file:\n")
    try:
        key = int(input("Enter the key shift:\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Use only in integers!")
    except:
        print("use only in integers!")
    try:
        with open(fileDest, "r") as file:
            with open(fileDest + "__encrypt.txt", "w") as encrypt_file:
                for line in file:
                    encrypt_file.write(encrypt(line, key))
    except OSError:
        print("""Error: \nMake sure you enter the path without any unnecessary spaces ,letters, symbols.
Or the file you entered does not exist.""")
    except:
        print("The file you entered does not exist")
elif options == 2:
    print("You have chosen to decrypt a file")
    fileDest = input("Please enter the path to the file:\n")
    try:
        key = int(input("Enter the key shift:\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Use only in integers!")
    except:
        print("use only in integers!")
    try:
        with open(fileDest, "r") as file:
            with open(fileDest + "__decrypt.txt", "w") as decrypt_file:
                for line in file:
                    decrypt_file.write(decrypt(line, key))
    except OSError:
        print("""Error: \nMake sure you enter the path without any unnecessary spaces ,letters, symbols.
Or the file you entered does not exist.""")
    except:
        print("The file you entered does not exist")
```

For example, this is what I get when I do decrypt with key 100:

```
¾²³½ ³½ « ¾¯½¾ °¹¼ ½¾«­µ¹à¯¼°¶¹á
```

This is what the encrypt looks like with key 100:

```
¾²³½ ³½ « ¾¯½¾ °¹¼ ½¾«­µ¹À¯¼°¶¹Á
```

This is the original text:

```
This is a test for stackoverflow
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encounter is due to the way you handle the character numerical value.
You do a check to see if it is outside the bound of letter values by doing

```
    if num > ord("z"): 
        num -= 26
    elif num < ord("a"):
        num += 26
```

Unfortunately, it only works for shift values smaller or equal to 26.
You could use a modulo operation instead of what you are currently doing.
There is also a different approach when you realize Caesar Cipher gives you the exact same result if you add or subtract 26 to the shift value.
Thus by simply doing: `shift %= 26` at the beginning of your code, it becomes valid for all values

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
            if num > ord("z"): 
                num -= 26
            elif num < ord("a"):
                num += 26
```

to:

```
            num = ord('a') + (num - ord('a') % 26
```

to keep `num` in range from `ord('a')` to `ord('z')`.